# Prevent optional group from being matched by preceding wildcard

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to read movie names and years. The pattern is as follows:
`name (year)`. The name of the movie can have all sorts of characters. And I came up with this pattern:

`^(?P<name>.*) \((?P<year>\d*)\)`

However, not all movies come with a year after them, so I would like make the `year` group optional such that it returns blank if only the name of the movie is there.

I know I can make the year optional with `?` but then it ends up becoming part of the `name` group.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks for the feedback; reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first part is too greedy. If you make the second part optional it will match everything. So, `*` → `*?`

Then you can use a optional non-capturing group for the year. And don't forget to mark the end:

```
^(?P<name>.*?)(?: \((?P<year>\d*)\))?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/zTZd9a/2

Comment: Thanks! This seems to get the job done. However, is there any way for the ```year``` group to return a blank match when there is no year in the string?

Comment: That would be possible but complicated due to the surrounding parentheses. I'd handle this in code.